# NServiceBus Sagas

Tags: nservicebus

I have a working pub sub sample and I want to look at sagas.  How can I configure the in mem saga persistence?

Answer (score 3):

Running the host in the Lite (default) profile will automatically use the InMemory persister.

Comment: In the end all I needed to do was add a reference to SQL Lite assmebly so it seems SQLLite is the default.

Comment: Sqlite is used when using the integration profile. If you copied the pubsub sample this is probably already set in you debug-> commandline parameters if you look at the properties of the csproj

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project file and click on Properties, then in the property pages, navigate to the Debug tab and enter NServiceBus.Lite under Command line arguments. This tells NServiceBus not to run the service  in production mode while we're just testing.